# "Recovering" another account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

First of I am aware that there is a function to merge two accounts together. I am also aware that you can recover your password by entering your email. My problem however is that I do not have access to my email address anymore.

The situation is that I had an internship at a company from around the area where I live and I used **Stack Overflow** to look up some information, to ask questions, and to provide answers.

After my internship ended, my email address got terminated (or at least I do not have access anymore). Knowing this, would it be possible to still merge my two accounts?

This account is my second account and my other is called: [Marco Geertsma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2086936/marco-geertsma).

I would understand if this wouldn't be possible from a technical point of view, but I would still very much like to have my old profile back.

Comment: As you can no longer edit the profile of your second account, [contacting the Stack Exchange team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) directly is probably your best option, as they may be able to verify your identity another way. From a technical perspective, however, there should not be a problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. I contacted them with the same question. I guess now i wait. Ill post their response here.

Comment: The stack exchange support staff contacted me last night asking me about my date of birth. They stated that once provided they would merge my two accounts back together.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP, this was resolved by using private knowledge entered on the profile:

> The stack exchange support staff contacted me last night asking me about my date of birth. They stated that once provided they would merge my two accounts back together.

So contacting SE is the way to handle this — they can figure out some way to verify the account ownership in most cases.